# Как правильно написать данный кусок кода в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет. Пытаюсь на практике изучать питон и написание телеграмм бота. Написал свой код на питоне, все работает, хочу сделать на его основе бота в pyTelegramBotAPI. Довольно много видео по созданию ботов, однако они все однотипные и не совсем понятно как превратить данный кусок кода (подобных кусков много) в жизнь. Через @bot.message_handler(): ?
подскажите как правильно написать данный код в телебота

```
def get_english ():
    while True:
        level_of_english = input('Укажите уровень английского 4 или 5. При отсутствии поставить 0. ')
        if level_of_english in ('0', '4', '5'):
            level_of_english = int(level_of_english)
            break
        print('Ввели неправильно!')
    return level_of_english
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите уровень английского 4 или 5. При отсутствии поставить 0")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_level_eng)


def get_level_eng(message: types.Message):
    # проверяем число ли ввел юзер
    if message.text.isdigit():
        if message.text in ('0', '4', '5'):
            print(message.text)
    # если не число, то требуем повтороного ввода
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите уровень английского 4 или 5. При отсутствии поставить 0")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_level_eng)
```